# Knockout highlighting row on condition basis

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to accomplish the following code to highlight row based on condition

```
self.highLightRow = function (row) {
   var today = moment(new Date());
   if (row.DueDt() !== '') {
        var d = moment(row.DueDt(), 'MM/DD/YYYY');
        if (d && d.isValid()) {
       if (today.diff(d, 'days') < 10) {
       return '#FFA500';
    }
    else if (today.diff(d, 'days') > 10) {
        return '#fdbcb4';
    }
  }
  else {
    return '#FFFFFF';
}
}
else {
 return '#FFFFFF';
}
    }
```

Which is not working as expected, my table is as follows

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: people">
    <tr data-bind="css :{ colorRow:highLightRow ($people) }">
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: DueDt"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I write 3 different conditions and binding it is working

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: people">
    <tr data-bind="css :{ white:$root.noColor($people) }">
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: DueDt"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want that to be in single function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
window.peopleVM= new peopleViewModel();
window.peopleVM.Init();
});
function peopleViewModel() {
     var self = this;
     self.employeeList = ko.observableArray();
     self.Init = function () {
     ko.applyBindings(self, $("#myDiv")[0]);
    }
}
```

I am making an ajax call to load the data as follows

```
self.LoadEmployees = function () {
        self.IsLoaded(false);
        var jqxhr = $.get(
            window.WebApiBase + "GeData",
            function (data) {
                self.IsLoaded(true);
                if (data && data.length > 0) {
                    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                        if (item) {
                            self.employeeList.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(item));
                        }
                    });
                    self.IsLoading(false);
                }
                else {
                    self.IsLoading(false);
                }
            })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, status, errorThrown) {

        });
        return jqxhr;
    }
```

Comment: What's the `self` referring to in your function? Show your data model and more of your view model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are still thinking about Knockout in imperative terms (i.e. "what would I need to do in jQuery?"). That's not helpful. Don't try to "call a function for every row", instead think "calculate a value and bind the view to it".

1. You have a list of people.
2. Every person in that list has a couple of properties, like `name` and `DueDt`
3. For every such person, an urgency ("due soon", "due later", "unknown") can be computed from the due date.
4. Row color is a result of that urgency value.

1 and 2 are basic properties of your data model. 3 is supplied by the viewmodel. 4 is dealt with in the view via CSS.

When every `Person` object computes its own `urgency` value:

```js
// viewmodel for a single person
function Person(data) {
  var self = this;
  
  self.name = data.name;
  self.DueDt = data.DueDt;
  self.isSelected = ko.observable(false);
  self.urgency = ko.pureComputed(function () {
    var d = moment(self.DueDt, 'MM/DD/YYYY');
    if (d.isValid()) {
      return d.diff(moment(), 'days') < 10 ? 'dueSoon' : 'dueLater';
    }
  });
}

// viewmodel for the overall list of people
function PersonList(data) {
  var self = this;
  
  self.people = ko.observableArray(data.people.map(function (p) {
    return new Person(p);
  }));
}

// sample data and viewmodel binding
var dataFromServer = {
  people: [
    {name: 'John Doe', DueDt: moment().add(20, 'days').format('MM/DD/YYYY')},
    {name: 'Jane Doe', DueDt: moment().add(5, 'days').format('MM/DD/YYYY')},
    {name: 'Jon Snow', DueDt: ''},
  ]
};
var vm = new PersonList(dataFromServer);
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
td { padding: 3px; }
tr.dueSoon { background-color: #FFA500 }
tr.dueLater { background-color: #fdbcb4 }
tr.selected { background-color: red!important; color: white }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.5.0/knockout-debug.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Due Date</td>
      <td>Selected</td>
      <td>Urgency</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: people">
    <tr data-bind="class: urgency, css: {selected: isSelected}">
      <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isSelected"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: DueDt"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: isSelected"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: urgency"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

...then the view becomes very simple and straightforward.

Note that the `class` binding is a feature of Knockout 3.5.0. With earlier versions of Knockout you could do

```
<tr data-bind="{selected: isSelected, dueSoon: isDueSoon, dueLater: isDueLater}">
```

and add `isDueSoon` and `isDueLater` computed boolean properties to `Person`.

Comment: Can I pass a value to my computed function? my table is a template which is used in common  across all the pages

Comment: `var colTemplate= '<!-- ko foreach: data -->\<tr class="row" data-bind="visible: IsVisible, css: {\'Selected\' : IsSelected }, ">';` this is the template code for my row binding

Comment: Okay I don't see where the row color comes into play here?

Comment: I need to call the function inside that, so how can I do that

Comment: Inside *what*? You need to be specific, I can't read your mind. Also, try to understand my answer. Thinking "I need to call the function" is not very useful in Knockout. Make observables/computed values and bind your view to them.

Comment: some how I need to `css: {\'Selected\' : IsSelected }` adopt the code inside that

Comment: Put an `self.IsSelected = ko.observable(false);` into the `Person` viewmodel. This way every `person` tracks whether it is selected or not. Then bind like this: `data-bind="css: {Selected: IsSelected}, class: urgency"`. This way the `css` binding is responsible for the `Selected` class on the element, and the `class` binding will add whatever the `urgency` for that person is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190681/discussion-between-learner-and-tomalak).

Answer (score 0):

How about having with `attr` binding

```
self.highlightRow = function (row) {
        var today = moment(new Date());
        var d = moment(row.DueDtString(), 'MM/DD/YYYY');
        if (d && d.isValid()) {
            if (today.diff(d, 'days') < 10) {
                return 'orange';
            }
            if (today.diff(d, 'days') > 10) {
                return 'melon';
            }
        }
    }
```

Your tr should be

```
<tr data-bind="attr: {class: $root.highlightRow($people)}">
```